# Bootstrap navbar displaying 2 rows when screen size is not mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap3, trying to build a responsive navbar.  At normal resolutions, the navbar is taking up 2 rows.  At small resolutions, it (correctly) only takes up 1 row.

How can I make link4 and link5 appear on the same row as links 1-3? (fiddle below code)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" data-role="navigation"> 
<div class="navbar-header navbar-left">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-left left pull-left collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-right right pull-right collapsed navbar-link glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
    </button>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a>link1</a></li>
        <li><a>link2</a></li>
        <li><a>link3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav navbar-right">
        <li><a>link4</a></li>
        <li><a>link5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div
```

http://jsfiddle.net/katgucbw/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this `ul` code inside your `#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1` below the first `ul`. This will let you have these links on the same line on screen sizes larger than 768px.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav nav navbar-right hidden-xs" style="margin-right: 10px">
    <li><a>link4</a></li>
    <li><a>link5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also, inside `#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2`, add the `hidden-sm`, `hidden-md`, and `hidden-lg` classes on the last `ul` so it will only show up on phones (<768px).

[*Official Documentation on Responsive Utilities*](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

---

**Full Code:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" data-role="navigation"> 
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-left">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-left left pull-left collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-right right pull-right collapsed navbar-link glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a>link1</a></li>
            <li><a>link2</a></li>
            <li><a>link3</a></li>
        </ul> 
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav navbar-right hidden-xs" style="margin-right: 10px">
            <li><a>link4</a></li>
            <li><a>link5</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav navbar-right hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <li><a>link4</a></li>
            <li><a>link5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</div>
```

[**Working Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/7wF9lpKGY5)

Comment: @user3662896 You're welcome! I just realized that it needs to be `margin-right` instead of `padding-right` so it doesn't cause white space at the end of the `navbar`. I updated the code above and in bootply.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move your `navbar-right` to the same `navbar-collapse` element. Like that:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" data-role="navigation"> 
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-left">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-left left pull-left collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-right right pull-right collapsed navbar-link glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a>link1</a></li>
            <li><a>link2</a></li>
            <li><a>link3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav navbar-right">
            <li><a>link4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a>link5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Ramy, that works but I need each button to expand the proper div.  In my code, see that the first button toggles bs-example-navbar-collapse-1, and the second button toggles bs-example-navbar-collapse-2.